# changing reference after initialization in c++

Tags: c++

```
    class mClass {
public:
    int uu = 9;
};

    mClass m1;
    mClass m2;

    m1.uu = 8;
    m2.uu = 7;

    mClass& ppp = m1;

    ppp= &m2; //Is it possible to change reference?
```

Is it possible to change reference?
I can initialize reference with constructor with parameter of reference but I do not know
how to change it later.

Comment: Nope.Best to think about them as a new name for the same object. When you use any variable by its name it is always an expression of l-value reference type to the object it represents.

Answer (score 5):

As shown in other answer(s) you cannot rebind a reference. If you want this feature you can:

- use raw pointers. There is nothing wrong with using raw pointers if you enforce the convention that all raw pointers are non-owning. A better choice is [`gsl::not_null`](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ri-nullptr) from the C++ Guidelines Support Library (both for code safety and code self-documentation).
- use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). Its [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%3D) rebinds the reference.

Comment: "enforce all raw pointers are non-owning" is there a good way to enforce that? I mean other than avoiding raw `new`?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 • Alas, no way to enforce that in the language.  Can be enforced using social engineering, such as threats of unemployment or ridicule by your peers.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 might be some linting tools that can do that (I personally don't know). However I feel that in this case just good practices and code reviews should be enough. I mean most likely you either have a mess of a legacy code with `new` and `char*` everywhere or you have a modern codebase.

Comment: I remember that gsl has `owner` but I never bothered to look at the details or what it is actually good for

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. References are not pointers. Not being able to rebind a reference to refer to something else after initialization is one feature that distinguishes them from pointers (it actually is a feature not a limitation).

```
ppp= &m2; //Is it possible to change reference?
```

`&m2` is a pointer to a `mClass`, but `ppp` is a reference to a `mClass`. References are not pointers. When you write:

```
ppp = m2;
```

Then `m2` is assigned to the object that `ppp` refers to. Sloppy speaking a reference is nothing but an alias for the original object.

*PS* Note that `mClass& ppp = m1;` is not assignment, but initialization. It is a bit unfortunate that C++ uses similar syntax (`=`) for two different things and that might have contributed to your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change reference?

If you mean, is it possible to make it refer to something else then no, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

References share memory addresses of that it is referencing so it cannot be changed. The reason we can reassign pointers is they have their own independent address and store the address of the variable it is pointing to as its value. References are kind of like clones

Comment: "References share memory addresses of that it is referencing" strictly speaking this is not necessarily correct. You cannot know where or how the reference is stored in memory, because the adress-of-operator only tells you the address of the object that is refered to. Under the hood a reference can be realized as a pointer and that pointer is somewhere in memory. Also they arent "clones", because that would imply that that creating a reference creates a seperate object

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Do references even exist? I always assumed that they just resolve to whatever object they refer to and there is no actual reference "object"

Comment: @NotAProgrammer thats actually a good question. What a reference really is under the hood is left open by the standard, but i'd expect that pass by reference `void foo(int& x)` is under the hood not much different from `void foo(int* x)`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I did say kind of lol but on reflection, yes bad example as a clone could take changes without affecting the original. As for it sharing the address if you print the address of both the original variable and the reference, you would get the same address.

Comment: @JamesVickers thats because in `int x = 0; int& ref = x; int* p = &ref;` the value of `p` is the adress of `x`. You cannot know where or if at all the reference occupies memory

Comment: or consider `struct foo { int& x; };` the reference does occupy some memory as member of an instance of `foo` and that is not the memory where the actual `int` is stored. Nevermind, I am nitpicking on a high level ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 it's Stackoverflow, I'd be worried if there was no nitpicking haha